# Magento 2: Move up-sell product to product.info.details tab

Tags: magento2, product, xml, tabs, up-sells

I would like to move my up-sell products into a custom tab on product view page and can't find a way. How can it be done by modifying **catalog_product_view.xml**.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **1.** Add below code to **catalog_product_view.xml** to remove old block

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true"/>
```

> **2.** Add new **upsell** block to **product.info.details**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="upsell.tab" as="upselltab" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
         <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Upsell</argument>
         <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

> Finshed example **catalog_product_view.xml**

So your new catalog_product_view.xml within theme should look like below (if there are no other modifications):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<!--remove original block-->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true"/>
<!--add the new block within product details tab-->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="upsell.tab" as="upselltab" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
         <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Upsell</argument>
         <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

> **File Location:** app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

**Changing the Tab Title**

Change title of tab within title argument of the added upsell block **e.g.**

```
 <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">You May be Interested In...</argument>
```

> **Tested on Magento 2.1.7**

[image: Upsell Tab]

Comment: It is possible to move upsell products below description in Details tab?

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this with XML like above. Only way I can think of seems a bit messy of top of my head. That is the details.phtml within Catalog module product/view folder. You could maybe check if alias is description and add additional code into there after the description. This could get quite involved however making that whole upsell block work within there. Ask another question and see if anyone has any better ideas?

Comment: @harri i follow your code and it's working fine but when some product does not have upsell product but custom tab is still displaying can you give any kind of solution?

Comment: @Magento of the top of my head I would look at possibly an observer that checks the number of upsell products and then modifies the layout to remove the upsell.tab block conditionally.

Comment: @harri if possible can you check it and give me solution for that?